# SQL query error about movie.title is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP(100) M.title, count(WH.movie_id)
FROM Movie AS M 
inner join WatchHistory AS WH ON M.movie_id = WH.movie_id
GROUP BY WH.movie_id, M.title, count(WH.movie_id)
ORDER BY count(WH.movie_id) ASC;
```

> BlockquoteColumn 'Movie.title' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My assignment is to do the following query:

Show 100 films that have gone so far
were looked at. This also means 0 times [film title, number of times viewed].
Make a View for this information requirement.

It gives the error above

Comment: The query you posted cannot produce that error. But why are you grouping by your aggregate?

Comment: you don't group the aggregate.. remove the count(WH.movie_id) from your group by clause

Comment: Remove `count(WH.movie_id)` from group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of issues:

- `count(WH.movie_id)` removed from a `GROUP BY`
- Added alias `[CountViews]`
- Alias used in `ORDER BY` instead of aggregate

Fixed SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(100) M.title, count(WH.movie_id) as [CountViews]
FROM Movie AS M 
inner join WatchHistory AS WH ON M.movie_id = WH.movie_id
GROUP BY M.title
ORDER BY [CountViews] ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only group by M.title. If you intend to group rows, decide which columns will be grouped. Remember that only columns in the GROUP BY clause, in addition to aggregate functions such as COUNT, may ultimately be included in the SELECT clause. Grouped aggregate functions operate on sets of rows defined in a GROUP BY clause and return a summarized result. Examples include SUM, MIN, MAX COUNT, and AVG. In the absence of a GROUP BY clause, all rows are considered one set; aggregation is performed on all of them.